# Vectorize a long term

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I have the matrices $A \begin{pmatrix}a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23}\end{pmatrix}, W = \begin{pmatrix}w_{11} & w_{12} & w_{13} \\ w_{21} & w_{22} & w_{23} \\ w_{31} & w_{32} & w_{33} \end{pmatrix}, x = \begin{pmatrix}x_1 \\ x_2 \\ x_3\end{pmatrix}, b = \begin{pmatrix}b_1 \\ b_2\end{pmatrix}$

I'm interested in the derivatives of the function $f(W,x) = \frac{1}{2}|AWx-b|^2$

Writing it explicitly, I found that

$f(W,x) = \frac{1}{2}(a_{11}w_{11}x_1 + a_{11}w_{12}x_2 + a_{11}w_{13}x_3 + a_{12}w_{21}x_1 + a_{12}w_{22}x_2 + a_{12}w_{23}x_3 +a_{13}w_{31}x_1 + a_{13}w_{32}x_2 + a_{13}w_{33}x_3-b_1)^2 + \frac{1}{2}(a_{21}w_{11}x_1 + a_{21}w_{12}x_2 + a_{21}w_{13}x_3 + a_{22}w_{21}x_1 + a_{22}w_{22}x_2 + a_{22}w_{23}x_3 +a_{23}w_{31}x_1 + a_{23}w_{32}x_2 + a_{23}w_{33}x_3-b_2)^2$

I want to find the derivatives of this function with respect to all variables, and vectorize the result (as in, write it in terms of matrix product rather than summations).

For instance:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = (a_{11}w_{11}x_1 + a_{11}w_{12}x_2 + a_{11}w_{13}x_3 + a_{12}w_{21}x_1 + a_{12}w_{22}x_2 + a_{12}w_{23}x_3 +a_{13}w_{31}x_1 + a_{13}w_{32}x_2 + a_{13}w_{33}x_3-b_1)(a_{11}w_{11}+a_{12}w_{21} + a_{13}w_{31}) + (a_{21}w_{11}x_1 + a_{21}w_{12}x_2 + a_{21}w_{13}x_3 + a_{22}w_{21}x_1 + a_{22}w_{22}x_2 + a_{22}w_{23}x_3 +a_{23}w_{31}x_1 + a_{23}w_{32}x_2 + a_{23}w_{33}x_3-b_2)(a_{21}w_{11}+a_{22}w_{21}+a_{23}w_{31})$

This is clearly a scalar product of $\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}w_{11}x_1 + a_{11}w_{12}x_2 + a_{11}w_{13}x_3 + a_{12}w_{21}x_1 + a_{12}w_{22}x_2 + a_{12}w_{23}x_3 +a_{13}w_{31}x_1 + a_{13}w_{32}x_2 + a_{13}w_{33}x_3-b_1 \\ a_{21}w_{11}x_1 + a_{21}w_{12}x_2 + a_{21}w_{13}x_3 + a_{22}w_{21}x_1 + a_{22}w_{22}x_2 + a_{22}w_{23}x_3 +a_{23}w_{31}x_1 + a_{23}w_{32}x_2 + a_{23}w_{33}x_3-b_2\end{pmatrix}$

With the vector $\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}w_{11}+a_{12}w_{21} + a_{13}w_{31} \\ a_{21}w_{11}+a_{22}w_{21}+a_{23}w_{31}\end{pmatrix}$

the first vector, the long one, is $AWx-b$, so overall this derivative is

$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}w_{11}+a_{12}w_{21} + a_{13}w_{31} & a_{21}w_{11}+a_{22}w_{21}+a_{23}w_{31}\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b)$.

This is just for $x_1$. If we do the same for $x_2$ and $x_3$, we should reach that

$\nabla _xf(W,x) = \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}w_{11}+a_{12}w_{21} + a_{13}w_{31} & a_{21}w_{11}+a_{22}w_{21}+a_{23}w_{31} \\ a_{11}w_{12}+a_{12}w_{22} + a_{13}w_{32} & a_{21}w_{12}+a_{22}w_{22}+a_{23}w_{32} \\ a_{11}w_{13}+a_{12}w_{23} + a_{13}w_{33} & a_{21}w_{13}+a_{22}w_{23}+a_{23}w_{33}\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b)$

My question is how to vectorize the first term, and how to repeat this process for $\nabla _W f(W,x)$

**Edit:**

$\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}w_{11}+a_{12}w_{21} + a_{13}w_{31} & a_{21}w_{11}+a_{22}w_{21}+a_{23}w_{31} \\ a_{11}w_{12}+a_{12}w_{22} + a_{13}w_{32} & a_{21}w_{12}+a_{22}w_{22}+a_{23}w_{32} \\ a_{11}w_{13}+a_{12}w_{23} + a_{13}w_{33} & a_{21}w_{13}+a_{22}w_{23}+a_{23}w_{33}\end{pmatrix} = W^TA^T$.

Which means $\nabla _x f(W, x) = W^TA^T(AWx-b)$.

Is this result correct? Is it correct for larger matrices as well?

Just need to repeat this process for $\nabla _W f(W,x)$.

**Edit 2:**

In general, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w_{ij}} = \begin{pmatrix}a_{1i}x_j & a_{2i}x_j\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b)$

So

$\nabla W f(W,x) = \begin{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x_1 & a_{21}x_1\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) & \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x_2 & a_{21}x_2\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) & \begin{pmatrix}a_{11}x_3 & a_{21}x_3\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) \\ \begin{pmatrix}a_{12}x_1 & a_{22}x_1\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) & \begin{pmatrix}a_{12}x_2 & a_{22}x_2\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) & \begin{pmatrix}a_{12}x_3 & a_{22}x_3\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) \\ \begin{pmatrix}a_{13}x_1 & a_{23}x_1\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) & \begin{pmatrix}a_{13}x_2 & a_{23}x_2\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b) & \begin{pmatrix}a_{13}x_3 & a_{23}x_3\end{pmatrix}(AWx-b)\end{pmatrix}$

How do I represent this as a product of $A, W, x, b$?

Answer (score 1):

$\def\p#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
Your stated goal is to avoid summations, but it also aids comprehension (and reduces algebraic errors) to avoid sprawling component-based calculations.

Use a colon to denote the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; {\rm Tr}(A^TB)$$
This product can also be applied to vectors by treating them as rectangular matrices (set $\,n={\tt1}$) in which case it corresponds to the usual dot product.  The cyclic property of the trace allows the terms in such products to be rearranged in many equivalent ways, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
A:BC &= B^TA:C = AC^T:B \\
B:C &= B^T:C^T = C:B\\
}$$
Note that terms on the RHS and LHS of the colon must have *identical* dimensions.

For typing convenience, define the vector
$$\eqalign{
 y &= AWx-b \\
}$$
Write the function in terms of this new variable.
Then calculate its differential.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= \tfrac 12y:y \\
df &= y:dy \\
 &= y:(A\,dW\,x + AW\,dx) \\
 &= A^Tyx^T:dW + W^TA^Ty:dx \\
}$$
Holding $x$ constant (i.e. setting $dx=0$) yields
the gradient with respect to $W$
$$\eqalign{
\p{f}{W} &= A^Tyx^T = A^T(AWx-b)x^T \\
}$$
while holding $W$ constant yields the gradient with respect to $x$
$$\eqalign{
\p{f}{x} &= W^TA^Ty = W^TA^T(AWx-b) \\
}$$